# Problem with url rewriting for image resizing script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using an image resizing script on my website, and want to be able to use e.g. `/images/image.jpg?ar=2.08333&w=600` and rewrite it to my script i.e. `img.php?src=image.jpg&ar=2.08333&w=600`. I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)w=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^images/(.*.jpg)$   img.php?src=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But for some reason if i try to access images/banner.jpg it gets put through the script even though I've addded the RewriteCond. What is even stranger is that it works on my local web server on my computer but not on the live site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And `/images/banner.jpg` presumably does exist? (But `/images/<image.jpg>` in your initial example does not?) Although the 2nd condition that checks the query string would also exclude your initial example (`/images/image.jpg?ar=2.08333&w=600`) that you say you want to rewrite? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: What is wrong with my RewriteCond?

Comment: The 2nd `RewriteCond` directive is only successful when a URL parameter like `w=600` does _not_ exist. But, the URL that you say should be rewritten contains `w=600`, so it won't be rewritten (based on what you've posted). If it is being rewritten then it would seem that "something else" is doing this - which could also be a clue as to why `images/banner.jpg` (which presumably does exist) is also being rewritten?

Comment: How should I write the RewriteCond?

Comment: You should remove the `!` prefix on the _CondPattern_.